# $watch collection of variables and function console Type error in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to check few variables form imputes with one function return true/false all together using $watchCollection. Below is my js code.

```
  $scope.myFunction = function(){
    if( $scope.something.length != $scope.otherthing.length){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
};


$scope.$watchCollection(function($scope){
    return [$scope.abc, $scope.xyz, $scope.myFunction()) ; // *** error on this line
},function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(newValue));
    // newValue will be use validation..
});
```

using above code I get error in console TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.myFunction used in $watchCollection.

Comment: just init your $scope.something and $scope.otherthing to an empty string at the beginning of your controller.

Comment: Its already defined, Any other though, why Type Error while function combine in array ?

Comment: show the full code of your controller, we need the whole picture.

Comment: did you try to use $scope.$watchGroup?

Comment: Can't access $scope.something as it belongs to any other function... trying to make that in $rootScope.

Comment: let me insist : the error message is explicit. Either $scope.something or $scope.otherthing is undefined at this point in the code. Where did you define these ?

Comment: You are right Derek, At that point of time the $scope.something and $scope.otherthing are undefined, I have added if condition in $scope.myfunction to resolved the temporary error message... Thanks for your inputes..